# How can i get values from under type table to parent type table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im not sure if i formulated this correctly but i came upon a problem, Basically i made a type of object in SQL Developer HUMAN which contains ID, Name and Surname. I needed a type TEACHER so i made it as an under type of HUMAN with extra attribute. Later on i made a table containing teacher, so i thought all info inserted into teacher, that is the same for human would automatically go into table "all humans" but that didnt work. Is there a way to make some code, where  parent object would recieve all information from its under objects?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
table Humans
____________
id
name
surname

table Teachers
____________
human_id    -- foreign key to Humans table
grade_level
subject     -- math, history, etc. 

table Students
____________
human_id    -- foreign key to Humans table
student_info
```

`Teachers.human_id` and `Students.human_id` are foreign keys that reference `Humans.id`. To get all teachers, you might do something like this

```
select *
from Humans inner join Teachers
on Teachers.human_id = Humans.id;
```

That'll give you a result set with all of the columns from both tables, like

> id | name | surname | human_id | grade_level | subject

And you'd do the same to get all the students, replacing Teachers with Students in the above query.

Comment: @AgnijaOnukrāne You're welcome Please mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your issue.